# In git flow branching model, how can one create the release branch from master instead of develop?

Tags: git, git-flow

In the git flow branching model (as described in [this](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) post) states that one should create `release` branches by branching off of `develop`.

This can work nicely but as far as I can tell can also cause unintended changes to make it to the `release` branch. Let's say that you are working on features A, B and C and you merge them to `develop`. A few days later features A and B become stable enough for release but feature C is still behind. You don't want features A and B to be delayed because of feature C and you can't revert feature C from `develop` because other developers depend on it.

As a solution to this I thought branching the `release` off of `master` and then merging features A and C on to it.

*(I'm still not 100% familiar with git so some of my statements below might be completely wrong so please do clarify.)*

The problem with this is that because features A and B were in development together with feature C and the developers kept their feature branches up to date with the `develop` branch, some of C's code ended up in feature branches A and B. If I merge these branches on to the `release` branch then I might end up with code from C in there. I'm still getting used to the idea of rebasing but if I try using rebase instead of merge I get all these conflicts. Perhaps I could cherry pick the commits or something like that but this seems too complicated to do every time I want to put some code on the release branch.

Could you guys let me know if there is a easy way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As gtrig says, merging feature C into develop should be avoided until it's ready.

> We consider `origin/develop` to be the main branch where the source code of HEAD always reflects a state with the latest **delivered** development changes for the next release. Some would call this the “integration branch”. This is where any automatic nightly builds are built from.

There are different ways to fix this once it's been done, but branching off master is the wrong way to go. If you branch off master then you either won't be getting any new features or you'll be cherry-picking commits or otherwise creating new, untested versions of the software. You should branch off develop because that's the branch where new features have been tested (or at least they should have been tested).

If the problems with C do not require major work then they can be fixed on the release branch along with other bugs found in release testing.

If the problems with C do require major work then C should be reverted on the develop branch before the release branch is created. The major work could occur either on C's feature branch, which will cause a bit of pain when C is finally ready to merge into develop, or on a new feature branch, which would cause the history to be a little misleading, but would otherwise work.

If other developers are depending on C before it's ready for the develop branch then they should simply use C's feature branch, directly or from their own sub-branches.

Comment: We do use the `develop` branch as an integration branch but sometimes things go wrong so it takes a while to get it stable again. I thought reverting would be the way to go in special cases but wanted to know if there is another way to work through this.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

I think you misunderstood the [post](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) you mentioned.  It says, "Finished features may be merged into the develop branch...".

You wouldn't normally merge an unstable feature into the `develop` branch.

Comment: Yes, feature C should not be merged into develop until after it is ready.